# Geofire onKeyEntered is never triggered though onGeoQueryReady is called endlessly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

The code is given below. I have seen all the previously asked questions there they have made the mistake of writing wrong reference or not setting geofire using Geofire.set method .Please help

```
  private void georadius(final LatLng pickup)
    {
        //geo
        DatabaseReference r2=root.child("Active_Drivers");
        GeoFire mG=new GeoFire(r2);

        GeoQuery m=mG.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(pickup.latitude,pickup.longitude),radius);
        m.removeAllListeners();

        m.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
               if (driverfound==false) {
                   driverfound = true;
                   driverid = key;
                   driverlocation = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                if (driverfound==false)
                {
                    radius++;
                    georadius(pickup);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "Active_Drivers" : {
    "LgEnzsB4y3g0tQZEnIMJRFnnREU2" : {
      "location" : {
        ".priority" : "ttqwsbkq5d",
        "g" : "ttqwsbkq5d",
        "l" : [ 30.6762423, 76.85536 ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Customer Requests" : {
    "nCz2Rlk2SafeTXWarBs4T8EiIdm2" : {
      "location" : {
        ".priority" : "ttqwsbu1fy",
        "g" : "ttqwsbu1fy",
        "l" : [ 30.6782832, 76.8549792 ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON under `Active_Drivers` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did as you said...

Comment: It seems unlikely that `onGeoQueryReady` fires repeatedly if `onKeyEntered` doesn't. If you put a breakpoint on `if (driverfound==false) {`, does it ever get hit?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sir , I have debugged by using breakpoints, resulting in increase of radius to large numbers i.e 2076 etc which happeneed in onGeoQueryReady.. but onKeyEntered was never triggered...

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if you want I can show you screenshot of the debug screen

Comment: That data structure looks wrong. Compared to this https://geofire-9d0de.firebaseio.com/-LFikIgZmwlD8kTphL4e.json?print=pretty you have an additional `location` level for each child. I'm pretty sure geofire looks for `.priority` and `g` straight under each child.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes you were right...Thanks a lot it worked..You are awesome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure looks different from [this](https://geofire-9d0de.firebaseio.com/-LFikIgZmwlD8kTphL4e.json?print=pretty) example:

```
{
  "fish1" : {
    "g" : "pns0h0mf2u",
    "l" : [ -53.435719, 140.808716 ]
  },
  "fish2" : {
    "g" : "u417k3dwub",
    "l" : [ 56.83069, 1.94822 ]
  },
  "fish3" : {
    "g" : "8m3rz3s480",
    "l" : [ 30.902225, -166.66809 ]
  }
}
```

You have an additional `location` level for each child. I'm pretty sure Geofire looks for `.priority` and `g` straight under each child.

Comment: van I have correctly implemented geofire , OnGeoQueryReady called and doing his work but onKeyEntered and onKeyExited never called . You can see my problem here https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/issues/66#issuecomment-523082930

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post a new question instead of commenting on previous answer. Be sure to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into your new question.